# How to arrive at Ramanujan's nested radicals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

Ramanujan found that $\sqrt[3]{\cos\left(\frac {2\pi}{7}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\cos\left(\frac {4\pi}{7}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\cos\left(\frac {8\pi}{7}\right)}=\sqrt[3]{\frac {1}{2}\left(5-3\sqrt[3]{7}\right)}$ on the last page of Ramanujan's second notebook.

He also found that $\sqrt[3]{\sec\left(\frac {2\pi}{9}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\sec\left(\frac {4\pi}{9}\right)}-\sqrt[3]{\sec\left(\frac {\pi}{9}\right)}=\sqrt[3]{6\sqrt[3]{9}-6}$

My question: How do we find the denesting with only the knowledge on the nested radical? Example: How would you find the denestings for $\sqrt[3]{\frac {1}{2}\left(5-3\sqrt{7}\right)}$ without knowledge on $\sqrt[3]{\cos\left(\frac {2\pi}{7}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\cos\left(\frac {4\pi}{7}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\cos\left(\frac {8\pi}{7}\right)}$?

Comment: What denesting?  The other terms in these equations are also nested radicals.

Comment: @RobertIsrael : The expressions on the right are nested; the ones on the left are denested. $\qquad$

Comment: $\cos(2\pi/7)$ etc. are irrational numbers, which can be written using radicals.  How do you denest their cube roots?

Comment: I'm saying that the radical within the radical is the nested radical. For example; in $$\sqrt[3]{\cos\left(\frac {2\pi}{7}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\cos\left(\frac {4\pi}{7}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{\cos\left(\frac {8\pi}{7}\right)}=\sqrt[3]{\frac {1}{2}(5-3\sqrt[3]{7})}$$. the LHS is the denesting, and the RHS is the nested radical...

Comment: All such types of identities follow from a general theorem from Ramanujan's Fourth Notebook (Entry 10, Page 22 of Bruce C. Berndt's version), which is discussed in this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2278338/proving-ramanujans-nested-cube-root).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those identities are not difficult to prove once established. For instance, $\alpha=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right),\beta=\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{7}\right),\gamma=\cos\left(\frac{6\pi}{7}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{8\pi}{7}\right)$ are algebraic conjugates, roots of the polynomial:
$$ p(x) = 8x^3+4x^2-4x-1.$$
If follows that $\alpha^{1/3},\beta^{1/3},\gamma^{1/3}$ are roots of the polynomial:
$$ q(x) = 8x^9-4x^6-4x^3-1 $$
and it is not difficult to compute, from $q(x)$, a polynomial that vanishes over $\alpha^{1/3}+\beta^{1/3}+\gamma^{1/3}$.
With some god-like inspiration, one may notice that
$$ r(x) = 4x^9-30x^6+75x^3+32 $$
is a factor of such polynomial. Then the conjecture
$$ \alpha^{1/3}+\beta^{1/3}+\gamma^{1/3} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{5-3\sqrt[3]{7}}{2}} $$
is natural, since $r(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of the RHS, and it is straightforward to check.
However, how Ramanujan actually *saw* that is a mystery to me. Probably the term *genius* was forged for a reason.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: thanks for the edit.

Comment: All such types of identities follow from a general theorem from Ramanujan's Fourth Notebook (Entry 10, Page 22 of Bruce C. Berndt's version), which is discussed in this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2278338/proving-ramanujans-nested-cube-root).

Answer (score 3):

Let's see if I can do something similar to Jack's answer for the second one.  I'm not Ramanujan, but I have Maple.

$\sec(2\pi/9), \sec(4\pi/9), \sec(8\pi/9)$ are roots of $t^3 - 6 t^2 + 8$.
If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are cube roots of these, $\alpha^{1/3} + \beta^{1/3} + \gamma^{1/3}$ will satisfy the following polynomial:

```
factor(evala(Norm(add(RootOf(_Z^3-RootOf(t^3-6*t^2+8,t,index=i)),i=1..3)-z)));
```

$$- \left( {z}^{18}-72\,{z}^{15}+2484\,{z}^{12}-19008\,{z}^{9}+31104\,{z
}^{6}+46656\,{z}^{3}+46656 \right) ^{6} \left( {z}^{9}+18\,{z}^{6}+108
\,{z}^{3}-1728 \right) ^{6}{z}^{18} \left( {z}^{9}-162\,{z}^{6}+157464
 \right)  \left( {z}^{18}+972\,{z}^{12}+69984\,{z}^{6}+1259712
 \right) ^{3} \left( {z}^{27}-162\,{z}^{24}+9612\,{z}^{21}-480384\,{z}
^{18}+16275168\,{z}^{15}-460269216\,{z}^{12}+7616887488\,{z}^{9}-
85571676288\,{z}^{6}+116784820224\,{z}^{3}+1833767424 \right) ^{3}
 \left( {z}^{27}-162\,{z}^{24}+9612\,{z}^{21}-141696\,{z}^{18}-2667168
\,{z}^{15}-131935392\,{z}^{12}+687911616\,{z}^{9}+28348838784\,{z}^{6}
+193536552960\,{z}^{3}+145199817216 \right) ^{3} \left( {z}^{27}-108\,
{z}^{21}-6048\,{z}^{18}-54432\,{z}^{15}-54432\,{z}^{12}-451008\,{z}^{9
}+1399680\,{z}^{6}-559872\,{z}^{3}-373248 \right) ^{6} \left( {z}^{27}
-108\,{z}^{21}+6048\,{z}^{18}-54432\,{z}^{15}+54432\,{z}^{12}-451008\,
{z}^{9}-1399680\,{z}^{6}-559872\,{z}^{3}+373248 \right) ^{6}
$$

The factor that is $0$ for the sum of the real cube roots is 
$$ z^9+18 z^6+108 z^3-1728$$

and the real root of that is $\sqrt[3]{-6 + 6 \sqrt[3]{9}}$.

I don't see how you could go in the reverse direction, starting with
$\sqrt[3]{-6 + 6 \sqrt[3]{9}}$ and finding a representation for it (and I doubt that Ramanujan did it that way either).

EDIT: In the same vein:

$$ \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{9}\right)^{1/3} +  \cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{9}\right)^{1/3} +  \cos\left(\frac{8\pi}{9}\right)^{1/3} = \frac{\sqrt [3]{-24+12\,\sqrt[3]{9}}}{2}$$

Comment: What is Maple? It seems to be some sort of supercomputer... Kinda like Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com) is a computer algebra system.  You could probably do similar computations with Mathematica, Sage, etc.

Comment: Do we have some clues on how ramanujan arrived at these results? Did he compute that by hand or some other way?

Comment: @Ant He computed the results by hand. But no one is really sure *how*. Back then, there weren't such things as mathematical computing softwares.